# Missing current folder Capistrano Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capistrano, rvm-capistrano

I need to understand why capistrano doesn't create the folder current. I'm using the following command : cap deploy:setup, cap deploy:check, cap deploy

But when i check in my app directory, i don't current folder.

This my deploy.rb

```
# Execute "bundle install" after deploy, but only when really needed
require 'bundler/capistrano'

# Automatically precompile assets
load "deploy/assets"

# RVM integration
require "rvm/capistrano"

# Application name
set :application, "app"

# Application environment
set :rails_env, :production

# Deploy username and sudo username
set :user, "ubuntu"
default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true


#We don't want to use sudo (root) - for security reasons

set :use_sudo, false

#Target ruby version

set :rvm_ruby_string, '1.9.3-p374'

#System-wide RVM installation

set :rvm_type, :user

#We use sudo (root) for system-wide RVM installation

set :rvm_install_with_sudo, true

#git is our SCM

set :scm, :git

#Use github repository
set :repository, "git@github.com:.../CM.git"

#master is our default git branch

set :branch, "master"

#Deploy via github

set :deploy_to, "/var/www/app/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

#We have all components of the app on the same server
server "125.156.125.125", :app, :web, :db, :primary => true

namespace :deploy do
 task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
  run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
 end
 task :symlink_shared do
  run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/assets #{release_path}/public/assets"
 end
 task :assets do
     system "rsync -vr --exclude='.DS_Store' public/assets #{user}@#{application}:#      {shared_path}/"
 end
end
after 'deploy:update_code', 'deploy:symlink_shared'
```

I don't understand where is the error, if someone can i help me ?
Thanks you

Comment: Capistrano should create these directories under your application deploy path 'releases', 'shared' and 'current' (this is a sym link to releases/xxxx) can't remember but it might not get created until first deploy, your app appears to be configured to deploy to "/var/www/app/app" - check that is the case and double check the deploy user owns the directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capistrano creates a current symlink (not directory) as one of the last steps in it's deployment cycle, generally right before the application server gets sent a start/restart command. It cannot create that symlink before deploying as there is nothing to symlink to (no checkouts in `/releases`).

If it's still not creating the symlink, check your capistrano deploy logs for an error, it won't create the symlink if it has an error before making it to that point. And if there is an error, please post it in your question.

Comment: I just comment load deploy:assets in my capfile and now capistrano creates current symlink.

Answer (score 6):

It could fail due to folder permissions also.
If the option

```
set :use_sudo, false
```

was not present when the first time cap was deployed, the current folder have sudo as the owner. When the user is changed, it might not have sufficient permissions to update the link.
I deleted the symbolic link and ran

```
cap deploy:create_symlink
```

This updated the symbolic link for me.

Comment: I never have these tasks `setup`, `create_symlink`, etc--where do you get them?!

Comment: You can find it here: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/capistrano-tasks